# How to pass value from dependency service to shared code

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the last call duration on my xamarin.forms app. On android part I am using dependency service.I can get the call duration. How to pass the duration to shared code back?

**My Implementation on Android**

```
class Dialer : ICallerDialer
    {
        public void GetCallLogs()
        {
            string queryFilter = String.Format("{0}={1}", CallLog.Calls.Type, (int)CallType.Outgoing);
            string querySorter = String.Format("{0} desc ", CallLog.Calls.Date);
            ICursor queryData1 = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(CallLog.Calls.ContentUri, null, queryFilter ,null, querySorter);
            int number = queryData1.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Number);
            int duration1 = queryData1.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Duration);
            if (queryData1.MoveToFirst() == true)
            {
                String phNumber = queryData1.GetString(number);
                String callDuration = queryData1.GetString(duration1);  

                How to pass this to Shared code back?
            }
           return;
        }
    }
```

**My Interface**

```
public interface ICallerDialer
    {
        void GetCallLogs(); 
    }
```

**Dependency call when button click**

```
  async void btnCall_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {         
            DependencyService.Get<ICallerDialer>().GetCallLogs();
           //How to get duration here?
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the return type of your method to string type.

```
class Dialer : ICallerDialer
    {
        public string GetCallLogs()
        {
            string queryFilter = String.Format("{0}={1}", CallLog.Calls.Type, (int)CallType.Outgoing);
            string querySorter = String.Format("{0} desc ", CallLog.Calls.Date);
            ICursor queryData1 = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(CallLog.Calls.ContentUri, null, queryFilter ,null, querySorter);
            int number = queryData1.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Number);
            int duration1 = queryData1.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Duration);
            if (queryData1.MoveToFirst() == true)
            {
                String phNumber = queryData1.GetString(number);
                String callDuration = queryData1.GetString(duration1);  

                return callDuration;
            }
           return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

**Interface**

```
public interface ICallerDialer
    {
        string GetCallLogs(); 
    }
```

**Dependency call when button click**

```
async void btnCall_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {         
           var duration = DependencyService.Get<ICallerDialer>().GetCallLogs();

        }
```